# Changing Ruby native extension's tmp directory

Tags: ruby, gcc, rubygems

I'm not super familiar with Ruby, but am using a system utility that needs to build some Ruby native extensions. When I attempt to run the installation command, I get the following stacktrace:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sensu-plugins-http:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.2/ext/unf_ext
/opt/sensu/embedded/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20161128-17526-tzlgio.rb extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lstdc++... yes
creating Makefile

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/unf_ext-0.0.7.2/mkmf.log

current directory: /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.2/ext/unf_ext
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.2/ext/unf_ext
make "DESTDIR="
compiling unf.cc
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wdeclaration-after-statement’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wimplicit-function-declaration’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
unf.cc:75:1: fatal error: error writing to /tmp/ccyXxObQ.s: No space left on device
compilation terminated.
make: *** [unf.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

For various reasons, my `/tmp/` directory is intentionally small. I was wondering, is there a way to get Ruby/gcc to use a different temporary location for the build process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Set the `TMPDIR` environment variable before compiling:

> TMPDIR
>
> If `TMPDIR` is set, it specifies the directory to use for
>   temporary files. GCC uses temporary files to hold the output of one
>   stage of compilation which is to be used as input to the next stage:
>   for example, the output of the preprocessor, which is the input to the
>   compiler proper.

Source:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html